# Javascript not immediately updating webpage/appearing sluggish

Tags: javascript

On a webpage, I have a series of images that are acting as buttons.  When the user clicks on the image, I add a border via javascript (to show the user that they clicked the image), and then do some intensive client processing (adding a filter to a grid/table, and updating the table).

Even though I add a border to my image as the first step, it is not visually changing until the filter has been applied/table update has occurred, approx 3-4 seconds later. It is ACTING like the border update is getting put in a queue, and not processed until the PC is idle... because an adjacent 'console.log' command executes immediately.

The code actually being executed is:

```
  console.log('Button number 4 processing');
  // Add the border to the button
  document.getElementById("img_es").style.border = "2px solid black";
```

The end result is that the system seems sluggish to the end user.

In other systems/langauges, I can tell the PC to processMessages, aka empty the messaging queue, which causes the screen to update.  Is there anything comparable in Javascript/HTML ?

Comment: Did you try out my answer? Did it help?

Answer (score 0):

The browser render engine can get blocked if you do a lot of operations that touch the DOM.

Either delay the start of the long-running operation with the help of `timeout()` by a small amount of time (let's say 50ms):

```
 setTimeout(function(){ /* expensive calculations here */); }, 50);
```

Or you could wrap the image in a link and draw the border with the CSS pseudoclass `:active`, see [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:active). That should work asynchronously.

```
 a img {
    border: 0;
 }

 a:active img {
    border: 2px solid black;
 }
```